# Can we use Activity Intent on FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-intent, fragmentpageradapter

I've been a while off from Android... so looking back at my codes wondering if I could do some optimization...

I have tabs using FragmentPagerAdapter as here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter

So within tabs I inflate the layout and do basic stuff like initialize and setup each UI component like Text and so on. Pretty much the way it should be.

Now I have a very generic tab page layout which I isolate it on library for sharing purpose among other apps. This is like a general welcome page. So let's call it WelcomeActivity which reside on lib module and has its layout inflated from itself.

So on App1, App2 and App3 where I have FragmentPagerAdapter can we call WelcomeActivity on lib module for each swipe to "Welcome Tab"?

So I will skip this part

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
    View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
    return v;
}
```

and instead I will call WelcomeActivity on here

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), WelcomeActivity.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(myIntent); 
}
```

Is this possible? I tried but then WelcomeActivity will appear and never appear again when I swipe back to "Welcome Tab". Did I miss something?

Comment: Show the code where you called `WelcomeActivity`

Comment: Depending on how many tabs you have (and I suppose depending on the current memory/ CPU situation of your device), they are not destroyed when swiped offscreen so they don't need to be (re)created. Maybe you should start the WelcomeActivity from the Fragment's `onResume()`?